# Responsive Issue - Images Causing Width Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on making http://preview.j64e7zzvo82p4x6r4fdjze6piimmfgviwsruf9j89pidaemi.box.codeanywhere.com/ responsive and for some reason there are images that are too big that cause the width of the body to be larger than the viewport.

The problem starts as soon as the screen is sized down to anything below 991px.

If I load the page with no images then it is fine but I am currently hiding the images by using (display:none;) when the screen is sized for mobile devices. So I don't understand why it is still happening.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For images to be responsive in bootstrap, you need to add the class "img-responsive" to them. then they will fit nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the image is `900px` wide, to avoid that you need to set a % width to the image, eg:

```
.online-store-image img{ 
  max-width:100%; 
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Or if you want to hide the rest of the image and maintain the same size, you can set:

```
.online-store-image{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

In this case you're using Bootrstrap, so you may want to add the `img-responsive` class to your images, so they can adapt to the container.

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition
>   of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height:auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.